# How to convert site to realtime script output

Tags: python-3.x

I Wonder if a can to make a webserver and in it to run the script and on some link ex(myscriptsite.com/main.html) to show the output console and allso to can write on it for inputs, like a client&server comunication on websites, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You mean something like [Python Fiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make an interactive terminal in your HTML website, you'd have to create some sort of text input field and bind a JavaScript function to the `keyup` event of that input field. That function should

1. Check if the pressed key was <kbd>Enter</kbd>, if yes, continue, if not return.
2. Read the contents of the text input field, clear the input field, and send the contents to a script on the server using an `XmlHttpRequest`.
3. Then, the script on the server has to execute the command and print out the output of the command. The webserver has to take care of sending that output back to your browser and JavaScript function.
4. Your JavaScript function has to put the output received from the webserver into some element on the HTML site.

I assume you have basic knowledge in Python because you have tagged this question with python-3.x. To achieve this, you will also need knowledge in JavaScript. If you have any more questions, please leave me a comment !

P.S. : If it does not have to be embedded in your own website, you could try [this online shell](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_bash_shell). You can type in or copy-paste a script  and then get a permalink to it using the share button on the top of the page. Your friends can even modify the script with out modifying the script you saved.

Comment: you know when you execute a python file it open a terminal with output I want that terminal to be on website like a client  and to able to write like a normal ouput terminal bun on website, like that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0eN_FhEBzs but only terminal

Comment: @Nick403 You mean, you want to have a real terminal embedded in your website, instead of a python console ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want, is possible? Like to store script on server and terminal of that script to be enbedded on website and to write on it input() allso , like a client&server on website.

Comment: @Nick403 this is possible, but not very trivial, because I cannot seem to find a library for that ...

Comment: Oh, and I cannot find anything , but I want to do that because all my friends to be able to use my scripts over internet, and website terminal, it was a good idea cuz script be in safe place and they to not be able to modify them just tot run, If you find how I can do that please leave me link or infromation here, thanks for help

Comment: @Nick403 does it have to be on your website ?

Comment: @Nick403 See my answer again, I edited it !

Comment: No, But must be a safe place tot store the scipts and they shubscripts

Comment: @Nick403 well, I think the page i linked in my answer is right for you !

Comment: https://www.onlinegdb.com/ is good but I want just te output terminal to share I don't want to share and source code too
"Your friends can even modify the script with out modifying the script you saved." I don't want that cuz then source code will Be leaked and they can bypass some basic If things

Comment: @Nick403 this is not possible with OnlineGDB I'm afraid. But you could look through the source code of their online bash interpreter for the client side (JavaScript function etc.), and the server side part is not too diifficult (Please do not expect I will write the server side source code for you !)